# How to disable clipping of bloom effect

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

The bloom effect in JavaFX 2 suffers from clipping which cuts parts of the effect itself. Is there a way to either avoid this clipping or to extend the region which will be preserved?

Example FXML (Just open with Scene Builder) which demonstrates the clipped bloom effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Rectangle fill="#808080" height="90.0" width="90.0" />
        <Circle fill="WHITE" radius="35">
            <effect><Bloom /></effect>
        </Circle>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

[image: bloomclipping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that this is a bug as an effect like dropshadow does not suffer the same clipping.  I encourage you to file the bug against the runtime project at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com.

A workaround is to set a transparent stroke on the circle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
    <Rectangle fill="GREY" height="90.0" width="90.0" />
    <Circle fill="WHITE" radius="35.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="10.0">
      <effect>
        <Bloom />
      </effect>
    </Circle>
  </children>
</StackPane>
```

[image: bloomok]

Comment: Great hack! This works for circles and other nodes which have a stroke. For labels one can use Text and for buttons... well there might be a way using CSS.
I have filed a bug: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26297